# Running CUDA on a virtual machine without a physical NVidia GPU card

Tags: cuda, virtual-machine, gpu

Is it possible to run a CUDA program on a virtual machine without having a physical NVidia GPU card on the host machine?

PCIe passthrough is only viable if the host machine has an NVidia card and that's not available.

One possible option to run CUDA programs without a GPU installed is to use an emulator/simulator (ex: http://gpgpu-sim.org/ ) but these simulators are usually limited.

I would appreciate a clear answer on that matter.
Thanks!

Comment: The one word answer is no is it not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run any modern version of CUDA (e.g. 6.0 or newer) unless you have actual GPU hardware available on the machine or virtual machine.

The various simulators and other methods all depend on very old versions of CUDA.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I expected this answer, however it wasn't explicitly stated anywhere. Searching for CUDA on virtual machines always led to answers that assume a physical GPU present.